# Which preposition to use for the reducing agent?

Tags: terminology

Which expression is correct when we use the prepositions *with* or *by* for indicating that the reduction is carried out using $\ce{NaBH4}$ as a reductor:

> It is reduced to sodium phenylselenolate **with** $\ce{NaBH4}$ in alkaline ethanol.

or:

> It is reduced to sodium phenylselenolate **by** $\ce{NaBH4}$ in alkaline ethanol.

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. I improved the formatting of your post; among others by including MathJax. For more information on how to do so yourself, check out the [help], [this meta-post](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/7475) or [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/444/7475).

Comment: Very funny, but there's  SE site for learning English, you know?

Comment: @Mithoron Well yes, *but* this is a rather specialistic chemical context. It *could* be that normal language requires preposition $x$ while chemistry speak requires preposition $y$. Thus I feel that it is OK to post the question here.

Answer (score 2):

Either is fine.  In the most literal interpretation of the statement I would say **by** (as it does the actual action of reduction), however I personally would likely use **with**, to a scientist there is little difference though.  If you were filing a patent, the term might might matter a bit more, which a quick survey of the patent literature suggests **with**.  Again though this is minutia and nit-picky.

I would suggest phrasing your sentence more as:

> ...is reduced to sodium phenylselenolate **with a solution of** NaBH4 in alkaline ethanol .

Comment: perfect, you are right , thanks for these clear explanations @Jan,@A.K

Comment: I don't think they're exchangeable, and you give the right example. "By" leaves no doubt about who the acting party is. "A is reduced by B", or "A is reduced by addition of B". If you say "A is reduced with B", I'm inclined to ask if there is also a "C". ;-)